# Blacklist (variable) not working discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I just made blacklist in my bot, and still I can use bot even though I blacklisted myself. This is my code:

```
BLACKLIST = ["my ID"]

@bot.command()
async def testblacklist(ctx):
  if ctx.author.id in BLACKLIST:
    await ctx.send("U r on blacklist!")
  else:
    await ctx.send("Test")
```

Can anyone help me with this? There aren't any errors in console and bot sends "Test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in `BLACKLIST` your id is a `str` and `ctx.author.id` is `int`. You have 2 options:

1. replace:

```py
if ctx.author.id in BLACKLIST:
```

with:

```py
if str(ctx.author.id) in BLACKLIST:
```

2. Put `int` as your id in `BLACKLIST`